# Set Selected Value of @Html.DropDownList to Querystring value or not

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, query-string, html-helper, html-select

I have a typical Create Action that was generated by scaffolding in MVC 4. Nothing fancy.
Normally I get to this page by the following URL `/RecipeLines/Create` and when I create that specific record I have a dropdown list I have altered to receive recipeID if sent:

```
    <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.RecipeID, "Recipe")
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.DropDownList("RecipeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.RecipeID, string.Empty)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecipeID)
    </div>
```

What I would like to do is link to the Create page by passing a recipeID, that would look something like this:

`/RecipeLines/Create/2`

I have edited the `@Html.DropDownList` to either accept a parameter and HOPEFULLY select the proper RecipeID or if it is linked to without the query string

`/RecipeLines/Create`

then it would not have a selected value.

Here is my Create Action as is.

```
    // GET: /RecipeLines/Create

    public ActionResult Create(int? recipeID)
    {
        ViewBag.MeasurementID = new SelectList(db.Measurements, "MeasurementID", "MeasurementEn");
        ViewBag.RecipeID = new SelectList(db.Recipes, "RecipeID", "RecipeNameEn", recipeID);
        ViewBag.IngredientID = new SelectList(db.Ingredients, "IngredientID", "IngredientNameEn");
                return View();
    }
```

My 2 @Html.ActionLink(s) looks like this:

```
    //Coming from the Recipe Page        
    @Html.ActionLink("+", "Create", "RecipeLines", new { recipeID = recipe.RecipeID }, null);

    //Coming from the RecipeLines/Index page
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

`THIS PROBLEM HAS BEEN SOLVED AND THE ABOVE CODE NOW WORKS`

Comment: Correction, it's not really a querystring I'm passing, simply a parameter which equals the RecipeID. Sorry about any confusion, but either way would work, I just want to be able to select the value of that Recipe drop down list if the URL contains some type of query string OR parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code:

**Create Action**

```
public ActionResult Create(int? recipeId)
{
    ViewBag.RecipeID = new SelectList(db.Recipes, "RecipeID", "RecipeNameEn",recipeId);

     //
    return View();
 }
```

**View**

```
  @Html.DropDownList("RecipeID", (SelectList)ViewBag.RecipeID,string.Empty)
```

**ActionLink**

```
@Html.ActionLink("+", "Create", "RecipeLines", new { recipeId= recipe.RecipeID }, null);

@Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
```

Comment: That just got rid of the `<option value=""></option>` at the beginning of the list

Comment: YOu know what, hold on, I might have missed something

Comment: hi @EricB, please check if you got right recipeId value, because it works for me.

Comment: If you're using ActionLink to call the Create Action, it should be like this: @Html.ActionLink("With id", "Create", "YourController", new { recipeId = 2 }, null) or @Html.ActionLink("Without id", "Create", "Home")

Comment: I have updated all of my code in my question to reflect the changes I have made. It still is not selecting the proper Recipe in the dropdown. And I agree  I think it should work. Maybe we are overloading something wrong?

Comment: hi @EricB, over here @Html.ActionLink("+", "Create", "RecipeLines", new { id = recipe.RecipeID }, null);, you need to use recipeID instead of id. like: @Html.ActionLink("+", "Create", "RecipeLines", new { recipeID = recipe.RecipeID }, null);

Comment: Ahhh, I had it right the first time then you updated your code with recipeID, then I did the same and didn't realize the Html.ActionLink still said id. Silly me. I appreciate all your help and patience. It's working fine now. Attention to details, I had not! lol